# Как добавить файл в под-папку при динамическом архивировании?

Tags: php, zip, архивация

Хочу добавить в архив папку в которой есть подпапки и в них файлы.

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

Использовать подобное не могу, т.к. мне нужны не всей файлы.

Есть массив с некоторой информацией о файлах:

```
$paths = [
    [
        'name' => 'file',
        'ext'  => 'txt',
        'path' => '/folder/'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'subFolder',
        'ext'  => 'folder',
        'path' => '/folder/'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'fileInSubFolder',
        'ext'  => 'txt',
        'path' => '/folder/subFolder/'
    ]
];
```

В цикле делаю проверку:

```
if( $folder[$i]['ext'] == 'folder' )
    $zip->addEmptyDir($fileName);
else 
    $zip->addFromString( $fileName.$fileExt, file_get_contents($fileFullPath.$fileExt));
```

Если "папка", то создаю пустую папку в архиве, иначе добавляю файл в архив.
Только если файл находиться в подпапке, то он добавляется в корень архива, а как добавить его в подпапку? Или как поменять текущую директорию для добавления?

Comment: А какая ошибка? чего не получаеться? И прежде раставьте скобочки везде.

Comment: Ошибок нету.
У меня есть структура mainfolder -> folder -> subfolder
В folder есть файл file.txt
В subfolder есть файл fileInSubFolder.txt

Я архивирую mainfolder, но в  архиве будет всё выглядеть так:
file.txt
fileInSubFolder.txt
folder
subFolder

Т.е. всё будет на одном уровне. В корне.

Какие скобочки расставить?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.
Нужно было в функцию `addFromString` первым параметром передавать путь к файлу + имя + расширение , а не только имя. Сразу не догадался. Думал, всё сложнее.